# how to get the length of the string in sqlcl

Tags: oracle, char, string-length, sqlcl

i am trying to display the top three rows based on their length of the string in names.but the system just reads the predefined length of the string column not the string in the column

```
SQL> select max(length(name)) from cus_detail;
```

```
MAX(LENGTH(NAME))
-----------------
               10
```

```
SQL> select * 
     from (select id, name, length(name) as namelen, distance 
           from cus_detail 
           order by length(name) desc
          )
     where rownum<=3;
```

```
        ID NAME          NAMELEN   DISTANCE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 paul               10         15
         2 baul               10         15
         3 mereum             10         20
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what `CHAR` datatype does - it right-pads value with spaces up to the full column length:

```
SQL> create table test (name char(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (name) values ('London');

1 row created.

SQL> select max(length(name)) from test;

MAX(LENGTH(NAME))
-----------------
               10

SQL>
```

A closer look:

```
SQL> select '#' || name ||'#' name, dump(name) dmp from test;

NAME         DMP
------------ --------------------------------------------------
#London    # Typ=96 Len=10: 76,111,110,100,111,110,32,32,32,32
       ^^^^                 L  o   n   d   o   n   ^^^^^^^^^^^
       spaces                                      spaces
```

So, you could `trim` the value:

```
SQL> select max(length(trim(name))) from test;

MAX(LENGTH(TRIM(NAME)))
-----------------------
                      6

SQL>
```

or - even better - change column's datatype to `varchar2`.